# Rails 6 app keeps losing Styles (MISSING BINDING)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am hoping someone can help me. Every so often when I start my server and load up localhost my app can not find the css styles. In the console I am seeing the following error. I have tried running "npm rebuild node-sass", "npm install" and a dozen other combinations with no luck.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could fix this?

Thanks so much for your help.

```
bootstrap.js:4511 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

Error: Missing binding /Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15)
    at Object. (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14)
    at Module._compile (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (:3000/profiles/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699)
    at Module.load (:3000/profiles/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598)
    at tryModuleLoad (:3000/profiles/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537)
    at Function.Module._load (:3000/profiles/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529)
    at Module.require (:3000/profiles/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636)
    at require (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161)
    at getDefaultSassImpl (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:198)
    at Object.loader (:3000/Users/gerarddonnelly/Desktop/rails6/legit1/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:80)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (bootstrap.js:4511)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (application.scss:2)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19)
    at Module. (application.js:1)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:24)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss @ bootstrap.js:4511
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:19
./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss @ application.scss:2
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ application.js:1
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:24
**webpack_require** @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83